# white bar at the top of my page

Tags: html, css

[Weird white bar at the top of my page, please help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzSWt.jpg)

I'm not exactly sure if this white bar with the ">" sign at the left has to do with my background photo in my CSS or if it has to do with my header top margin. please let me know what you guys think.

```css
#header {
 background:url('../img/stars-bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 height:100%;
 color:#fff;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
```

```html
 <section id="header"> 
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".8s" data-wow-duration="2s">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="logo"/>
        <h2>THINGS WORK BETTER IN SPACE</h2>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elitproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p class="hidden-sm-down">proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-6 header-right hidden-sm-down wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1.3s" data-wow-duration="2s">
        <p>qui officia d
        eserunt mollit anim id est laborum. qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <form>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="#" placeholder="Your name...">
         </fieldset>
             <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="#" placeholder="Your email...">
         </fieldset>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">sign up</button>
        </form>
       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row wow swing" data-wow-delay="2s">
       
      <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
       <a href="#social"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Given it's a >, I'm going to guess you have a malformed tag somewhere. Have you run this through a HTML verifier yet?

Comment: It's most likely a `>` sign somewhere in your code, do you mind posting all of your html?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it had to be a closing bracket somewhere in my code, The problem was it wasn't showing up in the validator for some reason and I thought it was somewhere in the header section of the body. After reading your responses I uncovered a link tag with two ">>" at the end of it. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an issue in your code with an opening/closing tag. I don't see an issue from what you've posted so I assume you haven't posted it all. In the future, you can validate your code [here](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: While this was my suspicion too, this answer should really be a comment until the OP gives more information.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it had to be a closing bracket somewhere in my code, The problem was it wasn't showing up in the validator for some reason and I thought it was somewhere in the header section of the body. After reading your responses I uncovered a link tag with two ">>" at the end of it. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @CiprianMicula if this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @kody very new to this I pressed the up arrow, is that what you mean?!

Comment: @CiprianMicula no worries - there should be a little check mark under the up and down arrows next to my post!